# Is there any way to change images size faster?

Tags: c#, winforms

Maybe in memory stream somehow ?

```
private void satellitesToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    file_array_satellite = Directory.GetFiles(UrlsPath, "RainImage*.*");
    for (int i = 0; i < file_array_satellite.Length; i++)
    {
        Image s = new Bitmap(file_array_satellite[i]);
        s = resizeImage(s, new Size(100, 100));
        s.Save(UrlsPath + "Changed" + i.ToString("D6") + ".jpg");
    }
    file_array_satellite = Directory.GetFiles(UrlsPath, "Changed*.*");
    if (file_array_satellite.Length > 0)
    {
        DateTime[] creationTimes8 = new DateTime[file_array_satellite.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < file_array_satellite.Length; i++)
            creationTimes8[i] = new FileInfo(file_array_satellite[i]).CreationTime;
        Array.Sort(creationTimes8, file_array_satellite);
        file_indxs_satellite = 0;
        file_indxs_satellite = file_array_satellite.Length - 1;
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }
}

public static Image resizeImage(Image imgToResize, Size size)
{
    return (Image)(new Bitmap(imgToResize, size));
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    file_array_satellite = Directory.GetFiles(UrlsPath, "RainImage*.*");
    for (int i = 0; i < file_array_satellite.Length; i++)
    {
        Image s = new Bitmap(file_array_satellite[i]);
        s = resizeImage(s, new Size(500, 500));
    }
    this.pictureBox1.Size = new Size(500, 500);
    pictureBox1.Location = new Point(this.Bounds.Width / 3,
                        this.Bounds.Height / 3);
    this.pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    pictureBox1.BringToFront();
}
```

In this case the pictureBox i'm showing the images in is in size of 100,100
So i changed the images size to 100,100 and show it in the pictureBox.
Then when i move the mouse over the pictureBox area the pictureBox is moving to the center of the form and i resize the pictureBox to 500,500 and also change the images size again to 500,500 and show them in the pictureBox.

The problem is that changing/converting the images size on the hard disk take almost 3-5 seconds each time.

Is there any faster way to make the size convertion ?

EDIT**

Changed the code trying to resize only the current display image but the images in the pictureBox1 now are not in the same size and i don't see the animation in the pictureBox.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {


                Image s = new Bitmap(file_array_satellite[file_indxs_satellite]);
                s = resizeImage(s, new Size(100, 100));
                pictureBox1.Load(file_array_satellite[file_indxs_satellite]);
                file_indxs_satellite = file_indxs_satellite - 1;
                if (file_indxs_satellite < 0)
                {
                    file_indxs_satellite = file_array_satellite.Length - 1;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                timer1.Enabled = false;
            }
        }

        private void satellitesToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            file_array_satellite = Directory.GetFiles(UrlsPath, "RainImage*.*");
            if (file_array_satellite.Length > 0)
            {
                DateTime[] creationTimes8 = new DateTime[file_array_satellite.Length];
                for (int i = 0; i < file_array_satellite.Length; i++)
                    creationTimes8[i] = new FileInfo(file_array_satellite[i]).CreationTime;
                Array.Sort(creationTimes8, file_array_satellite);
                file_indxs_satellite = 0;
                file_indxs_satellite = file_array_satellite.Length - 1;
                timer1.Enabled = true;
            }
        }

        public static Image resizeImage(Image imgToResize, Size size)
        {
            return (Image)(new Bitmap(imgToResize, size));
        }
```

Comment: Load the images into memory ahead of time.

Comment: Not sure if this is faster...it might be simpler though...take a look at Image.GetThumbnailImage();

Comment: It is pretty unclear why you iterate and resize an entire directory worth of image files when the picture box can only show one of them.  This is expected to be slow.  Write smarter code, only resize the displayed image.

Comment: Why are you physically resizing the image on the disk and then reloading it? .NET can stretch an image in the box for you, so you'd be better off using the maximum image size and letting .NET resize it to 100x100 for you. That being said...event .NET is really slow at doing this because it's relying on GDI+ (software rendering) to resize your image. So you might want to custom create your control for fast image rendering, or use WPF

Comment: Also, you are not disposing your Bitmaps, which will result in performance penalties as you leak unmanaged resources.

Comment: You only need to change the size of the PictureBox and everything else will be taken care of by it (is/when its properties are properly handled, of course), no need to resize the files: they only need to be as big as the bigger size you need.

Comment: looks like there's a thumbnail strip of images of weather satellite images, and being saved as a new filename. Lots of choices I'd think about revisiting in the architecture - maybe thumbnail when I'm saving the downloaded satellite image using async calls to preprocess? Maybe there's an intent to have a smoother, faster transition on the thumbstrip? picturebox1 might be a flying viewport that shows the 500x500 version of the moused-over thumbstrip?

Comment: Edited my question with the changed code trying to resize only the current image showing now in the pictureBox but it's not working. Can someone show me how thecode should be ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few problems with your implementation, fix these first:

- You're resizing from 500x500 to 100x100 and then back to 500x500 > quality loss of your image.
- You're not disposing your images.
- Why do you load all images and resize them if you only want to show one image? Just resize the image you hover over and then you don't even have to save them to disk.

Some general hints if you do want to show a LOT of images:

- Only load those images that you actually view in the GUI, load more once they start scrolling.
- If it's still slow, load them in a background thread and show them image by image once they are done.

Comment: Carra right. The reason i'm chagning from 500x500 to 100x100 is that i wanted to show the pictureBox and images inside bigger when you move the mouse over the pictureBox.  If i will use stretch or something else then convert the size of the images the quality won't be good either. If i change to 500x500 the quality is quite good. How the code should be like ?